# How to identify the clicked image where the image id tag is not static?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a list of images that is displayed in the html from the server using PHP code

[image]

Here is the PHP code that is inside a div:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb'><a class='thumbnail' href='#'><img id='template" . $row["imageName"]. "' class='img-responsive' src='../images/templates/" . $row["imageName"].".". $row["imageExtension"]."' alt='error' width='333px' height='262px' class='img-thumbnail' onClick='changeImage()'></a></div>";
}
```

The PHP code loops every image in the server and creates another div and inside it is the img.

Now, my problem is how can I identify the specific image clicked? I could not use the `document.getElementById('');` because in the first place I don't know the ID right? Although I made each of them unique IDs by adding the `id='template" . $row["imageName"]. "'` which means the supposed ID of each image is `template[x]` where `x` is the image name from the database.

I am struggling how I can identify the specific image that has been clicked by the user.

Is there any way I can identify the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$("img").click(function(){
   alert("Image ID is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This will show the ID of the image u clicked in a pop-up.

Basically the above code waits for a *click* on any `img` element on the page.

Once an `img` is clicked, u simply retrieve the 'id' *attribute* of the **clicked element** which can be referred to by `$(this)`, and hence display it in an alert box.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: `<script>
function changeImage() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var image;
    //ctx.drawImage(image,00,00,769,525);
    
    $("img").click(function(event){
   alert("Image ID is: " + event.target.id);
});
}
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.img-responsive').on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr("id");
});
```

It will create click listener for all images and we want to track for specific images only, images which has `img-responsive` class and once it got clicked we can easily access it using `this`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Hello @Jimish Gamit, where specifically should I put the sample snippet above? THANKS!

Comment: you suppose to add at end of the page between `<script type='text/javascript'>..</script>`

Answer (score 2):

If the images are loaded into the page via AJAX or some kind of dynamic method, you may need to use $(document).on(). Use the ".img-responsive" selector to select all images with class="img-responsive" for your page.

```
$(document).on("click", ".img-responsive", function() {
    alert("Image ID is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP use `.on()`?

Comment: Hi there, I tried putting your snippets inside the function `changeImage()` which is called by Onclick and most of the answers here works, it displays the id of the clicked image, but there's something creepy going on, on the first click, the alert does not run, on the second click, the alert runs the alert twice so it displays two alert dialog with same id.. Here's the function below:

`<script>
function changeImage() {
        
    $("img").click(function(event){
   alert("Image ID is: " + event.target.id);
});
}
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery:

```
$('.divclass img').click(function() {
   console.log('Clicked image ID ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

`.divclass img` because (or ID as `#divid img` if you wish) I guess it would be more efficient to target images only in that specific div, and not in the whole document.

You can also execute other JavaScript functions, passing the ID of the image as a parameter, or even the whole element, for example:

```
someFunction($(this)); // Transfer the whole element as an argument.
```

or

```
someFunction($(this).attr('id')); // Transfer just the ID as an argument.
```

And the function itself:

```
function someFunction(image) {
    // Do some things with the image.
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").click(function(event){
   alert("Image ID is: " + event.target.id);
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/Lpz917vo/5/)

[event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) :  The event.target property returns which DOM element triggered the event.The *event* parameter comes from the event binding function.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard :) I'll keep this and try to improve my answering style.